# Center content horizontally and vertically in HTML?

Tags: layout, html, center

I have a table which surrounds all the content of a webpage, I would like to center this table horizontally and vertically inside the browser window. It is a much smaller content area than that of the average browser so there should be no issues.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you are using the `table` to design the Web page, you should consider reworking the code.  You should avoid putting all your content in a table.  It is bad practice.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this code to the top of the html file within the HEAD tags:

```
<style>
table
{
    align: center;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Forgot to mention I'm a total noob, how to implement fully?

Comment: how to implement that later when i come to the table?

Comment: Could you please explain what do u mean?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to center your table.you can use `margin-left:auto;`
if you want to center your text inside table you can use `text-align:center;`